# MyFragment start new intent then if it close , it intent to MyFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I dont know describe it, like :
[image]

I want to click a button in fragment 1, it intent somewhere which contain layout for user edit profile, then user close it intent to fragment1 and update profile.

I used to activity but it always intent to default fragment, then I use dialog fullscreen but it can't use onAcitivityResult . what should I do?

Please help me

**have a nice day, everyone!**

There is my code for take picture in dialog, it work on activity but not on dialog

```
private void permit_camera() {
    PermissionListener permissionlistener = new PermissionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPermissionGranted() {
            Intent intent_take_picture = new 
 Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            takePicture.launch(intent_take_picture);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPermissionDenied(List<String> deniedPermissions) {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Permission Denied\n" + deniedPermissions.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    TedPermission.with(requireContext())
            .setPermissionListener(permissionlistener)
            .setDeniedMessage("")             
.setPermissions(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            .check();
}

ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> takePicture = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        result -> {
            if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK && 
result.getData() != null) {
                Intent intent = result.getData();
                if(intent.getData()==null){
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "null", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), 
 intent.getData().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Please show what you tried in code.

Comment: i don't know show which piece of code. i just want to ask how to create something that intent to fragment not default fragment

Comment: If you want to use dialog, you can create a callback (interface class), when user presses OK in dialog, it will dismiss dialog and trigger fragment via that callback then you can update fragment UI.
If you want to use activity with `startActivityForResult()`, you can call normally and register `onActivityResult` in this fragment. If this way does not work, post your code of this fragment here.

Comment: i tell you what i want to do.in fragment , i display a circle image of user.then if user click edit, it show the image it in dialog, if user change image on dialog,image on dialog change , it close and fragment update profile.

Comment: i was show code in post, please help me